# Cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref

Tags: python, python-2.7, ironpython

IronPython outputs the exception: "Python exception : Cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref". Here is my python code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'D:\Program Files\Python2.7\Lib')
import tarfile #error occurs only if importing tarfile

print('success')

sys.exit()
```

It runs successfully on cmd tool. Could anybody give some tips?
By the way,python version is 2.7.15 (latest on the official website)